# How to secure GET request to WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, rest, authentication

I'm new to REST API and still learning. I have a WordPress site with a custom post type called 'orders'. I'm using Crocoblocks JetEngine to set up the CPT. The thing is that when I make a GET request to the endpoint /orders/ whether using Postman or simply just entering the endpoint in an incognito browser, I get all the posts and their data in JSON.

My question is, is there no authentication needed? Can anyone on the internet simply just enter my endpoint in a browser and get all my post data? I know that's probably not how it works, but that's what is happening for me. My Postman request has no authorization or headers, but it returns all posts. Is there a setting in WordPress that I need to set to prevent anyone from making a GET request to my data?

Thank you.